# Error when running an exe under wine

Tags: wine

I can install [the pdfxchange editor "32 bit MSI Installer"](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads). But once I run the executable PDFXEdit.exe from bash by wine-1.7.18 on Ubuntu 12.04, I get

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000002 in 32-bit code (0x7e9a5522).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:7e9a5522 ESP:0329e280 EBP:0329e748 EFLAGS:00210286(  R- --  I S - -P- )
 EAX:00000002 EBX:7ea68ff4 ECX:0329e280 EDX:00000000
 ESI:0329e510 EDI:800401f0
Stack dump:
0x0329e280:  01ce6220 7ea37fcc 0329e64c 00000000
0x0329e290:  0329e638 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0329e2a0:  0329e5d8 0329e628 00000000 00000000
0x0329e2b0:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0329e2c0:  00000000 0329e318 0329e5d8 0329e88c
0x0329e2d0:  00001134 7ea2c973 127ff36b 7ea387bc
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7e9a5522 in ole32 (+0x55522) (0x0329e748)
  1 0x7e96d163 CoGetClassObject+0x5e2() in ole32 (0x0329e818)
  2 0x7e96d93b CoCreateInstance+0xfa() in ole32 (0x0329e8a8)
  3 0x1018ef8f in pdfxeditcore.x86 (+0x18ef8e) (0x01854358)
  4 0x00000002 (0x113412ec)
  5 0x10a2cb50 in pdfxeditcore.x86 (+0xa2cb4f) (0x106edfb0)
0x7e9a5522: movl    0x0(%eax),%edx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (128 modules)
PE    400000-  45f000   Deferred        pdfxedit
PE   1090000- 10c1000   Deferred        readoutloud.pvp
PE   10d0000- 111e000   Deferred        pdfoptimizer.pvp
PE   2360000- 2517000   Deferred        fileopensh.pvp
PE   2520000- 2799000   Deferred        ocrplugin.pvp
PE   27a0000- 2847000   Deferred        spellchecker.pvp
PE  10000000-1199b000   Export          pdfxeditcore.x86
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bce6000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bce6000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7cb74000-7cb9a000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7cb80000-7cb9a000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7cb9a000-7cbc9000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7cba0000-7cbc9000   \               netapi32
ELF 7ce6d000-7ce95000   Deferred        mlang<elf>
  \-PE  7ce70000-7ce95000   \               mlang
ELF 7cf95000-7cfad000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7cfad000-7cff7000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7cff7000-7d009000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d009000-7d08f000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7d08f000-7d0a1000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 7d0a1000-7d0aa000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d0aa000-7d0d2000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d0d2000-7d1a1000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d1a1000-7d1b3000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d1b3000-7d277000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7d277000-7d2b5000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d2b5000-7d308000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d308000-7d3d7000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7d310000-7d3d7000   \               crypt32
ELF 7d3d7000-7d465000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7d3e0000-7d465000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7d465000-7d48a000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d470000-7d48a000   \               imm32
ELF 7d48a000-7d4c2000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7d490000-7d4c2000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7d4c2000-7d514000   Deferred        liblcms2.so.2
ELF 7d534000-7d555000   Deferred        mscms<elf>
  \-PE  7d540000-7d555000   \               mscms
ELF 7d555000-7d60e000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7d560000-7d60e000   \               winmm
ELF 7d60e000-7d651000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7d610000-7d651000   \               usp10
ELF 7d651000-7d73d000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7d660000-7d73d000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7d73d000-7d780000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7d740000-7d780000   \               winspool
ELF 7d780000-7d7fc000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7d790000-7d7fc000   \               wininet
ELF 7d7fc000-7da32000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7d810000-7da32000   \               shell32
ELF 7da32000-7dad5000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7da40000-7dad5000   \               urlmon
ELF 7db64000-7db69000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7db69000-7db77000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7db77000-7dba2000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7db80000-7dba2000   \               msacm32
ELF 7dba2000-7dbc9000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7dbb0000-7dbc9000   \               mpr
ELF 7dbdc000-7dc18000   Deferred        libxslt.so.1
ELF 7dc18000-7dd65000   Deferred        libxml2.so.2
ELF 7dd85000-7de4a000   Deferred        msxml3<elf>
  \-PE  7dd90000-7de4a000   \               msxml3
ELF 7de4a000-7de77000   Deferred        msxml6<elf>
  \-PE  7de50000-7de77000   \               msxml6
ELF 7e11a000-7e150000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7e120000-7e150000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7e150000-7e156000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7e156000-7e161000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7e161000-7e172000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7e172000-7e176000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e176000-7e17f000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7e17f000-7e189000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e189000-7e18f000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e18f000-7e193000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7e193000-7e19a000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e19a000-7e19e000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7e19e000-7e1bf000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e1bf000-7e2f3000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e2f3000-7e305000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e306000-7e30a000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7e30a000-7e30f000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7e30f000-7e323000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e310000-7e323000   \               msimg32
ELF 7e325000-7e3b9000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7e330000-7e3b9000   \               winex11
ELF 7e424000-7e44e000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e44e000-7e482000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e482000-7e51c000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e51c000-7e53b000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF 7e53b000-7e55d000   Deferred        libncurses.so.5
ELF 7e55d000-7e571000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e560000-7e571000   \               psapi
ELF 7e591000-7e5f9000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e5f9000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7e5f9000-7e702000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e600000-7e702000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e702000-7e77c000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e710000-7e77c000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e77c000-7e8b1000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e790000-7e8b1000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e8b1000-7e934000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e8c0000-7e934000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e934000-7ea73000   Dwarf           ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e950000-7ea73000   \               ole32
ELF 7ea73000-7ea8d000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7ea80000-7ea8d000   \               version
ELF 7ea8d000-7eafd000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eaa0000-7eafd000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eafd000-7ec1c000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb10000-7ec1c000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ec1c000-7ed78000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7ec30000-7ed78000   \               user32
ELF 7ef78000-7ef85000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef85000-7ef91000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef91000-7efab000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7efab000-7efd7000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efd7000-7efe0000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7efe3000-7eff9000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF b7411000-b75bb000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF b75bb000-b75c0000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF b75c1000-b75dc000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF b75f3000-b75fc000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF b75fc000-b77b2000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF b77b4000-b77d6000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF b77d6000-b77d7000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 PDFXCview.exe
    0000002d   -1
    0000002c    1
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    0000001e    0
    00000016    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 FCUpdateService.exe
    0000001d    0
    00000019    0
    00000013    0
00000014 explorer.exe
    00000015    0
0000001b winedevice.exe
    00000024    0
    00000021    0
    00000020    0
    0000001c    0
00000022 plugplay.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000023    0
0000000b PDFXCview.exe
    00000033   -1
    00000037   -1
    00000046   -1
    0000003f    1
    00000045    0
    0000003d    0
    0000001a    0
0000002b PDFXCview.exe
    0000002e   -1
    0000002f    1
    00000036    0
    00000044    0
    00000040    0
0000004b PDFXCview.exe
    00000061   -1
    00000062    1
    0000004a    0
    0000004d    0
    0000004c    0
00000031 PDFXCview.exe
    00000034   -1
    00000038   -1
    00000067    0
    00000053    0
    0000005e   -1
    00000049    1
    00000048    0
    00000050    0
    00000051    0
0000003e PDFXCview.exe
    00000056   -1
    00000057    1
    0000003b    0
    00000047    0
    00000039    0
00000018 (D) C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Editor\PDFXEdit.exe
    00000066    0 <==
    0000004e    0
    0000005d    0
    0000004f    0
    00000059    0
0000005c TrackerUpdate.exe
    00000041    0
    00000064    0
    00000055    0
    00000042    0
    00000035    0
    0000005f    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.7.18
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.2.0-60-generic-pae
```

Is this a problem from Wine or executable? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deselect Tracker Update component in the installation options.